# New Rails App Fails loading assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to get a brand new skeleton app running in rails 3.1.0.rc8. However, whenever any asset tag/helper is used in a view(such as image_tag, javascript_include_tag, etc.), I get a asset compile error. Here's a snippet of my logs/development.log when I make a direct request to */assets/rails.png*.

```
Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 192.168.0.12 at Mon Aug 29 16:16:21 -0600 2011
Error compiling asset rails.png:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:101:in `respond_to?'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:101:in `dump'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:101:in `write_entry'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:20:in `atomic_write'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:101:in `write_entry'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:140:in `write_entry'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache.rb:364:in `write'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/cache.rb:362:in `write'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:117:in `cache_set'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:80:in `cache_set_hash'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:51:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:82:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/trail.rb:102:in `find_asset_in_path'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/base.rb:102:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:72:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.15) lib/sprockets/server.rb:42:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/prefix.rb:26:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.2) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:326:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
```

I'm running ruby 1.8.7 and Passenger, if relevant. Anyone else running into this error?

Comment: Do you still get this with Sprockets 2.0.0.?

Comment: Ah, upgraded to Sprockets 2.0.0 from 2.0.0.beta.15. Everything's happy now. Thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by upgrading from sprockets 2.0.0.beta.15 to 2.0.0:

```
gem install sprockets -v=2.0.0
```

Kudos to [Ryan Bigg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15245/ryan-bigg) for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when compiling assets via rake task:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
...
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:91:in `respond_to?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:91:in `dump'
...
```

after spending 4+ hours and tried many approaches, I found that it may be an issue of Ruby. ( from this link:  https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/issues/538 )

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0)
```

Here the `patchlevel 0` is the problem. since my ruby was compiled from the source code. (some reason I can't make it installed from package manager or via RVM).

Solution:

1. Download a new source file from http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/, e.g. patch 358 ,
2. compile it:

   ```
   unzip ruby-1.8.7-p358.zip -d /tmp && cd /tmp/ruby-1.8.7-p358 && ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```
3. now ruby has a new version: patch 358

   ```
   $ ruby -v
   ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]
   ```

   and everything works!